# Observe size change of element

Tags: javascript, html, resize, offsetwidth

**This is not a duplicate! I'm not satisfied with the result of other answers. If you still think it is a duplicate, please comment it before why you think it is!**

---

I have to observe size changes of elements. I've tried to do it by creating a setter on the `offsetWidth` property like this:

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

div.addEventListener("resize", console.log);
div.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(div.offsetWidth));


let width = div.offsetWidth;
Object.defineProperty(div, "offsetWidth", {
    get: () => width,
  set: val => {
    width = val;
    div.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
  }
});

document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => div.style.width = "200px";
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button>
Set size
</button>
```

Click on the red box to log the size. Then press the button. Nothing happens. If you click the box again, it will still show the old size. Why does this not work?

Comment: Have you considered a [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)?

Comment: You don't set `offsetWidth` (it's derived and read-only anyway) so your setter never runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered using a [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)?

```js
// get references to the elements we care about
const div = document.querySelector('.demo');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// wire the button to resize the div
button.addEventListener('click', () => div.style.width = `${Math.random() * 100}%`);

// set up an observer that just logs the new width
const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  const e = entries[0]; // should be only one
  console.log(e.contentRect.width);
})

// start listening for size changes
observer.observe(div);
```

```css
.demo { /* not really relevant. just making it visible. */
  background: skyblue;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button>Change Size</button>
<div class="demo">Demo</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking more for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Supported [everywhere but IE](https://caniuse.com/resizeobserver) and there's [a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill).

Comment: just be aware the resize event's wont fire for inline elements: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4507

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Internet Explorer supports `onresize` on all HTML elements. In all other Browsers the `onresize` is only available on the `window` object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize

If you want to have `onresize` on a div in all browsers check this:

http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

This library has a class `ResizeSensor` which can be used for `resize` detection.